# How to query and update a table in Access from Excel in one sub

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a Userform in Excel with four textboxes. Each text box corresponds to a field of Table1 in Access.

I’m would like to return MAX row ID value from a table in Access, add 1 to that value, and to display that value in a textbox on the userform.

After I enter values into the other 3 text boxes, I would like to export data to Table1 in Access.

Can this all be accomplished in the same subroutine?  Please help me incorporate sql statement in the correct location in the code.

Thank you

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim PrimaryField As String

Dim MyTable As String
Dim GetLastPrimaryKey As Variant

PrimaryField = "ID"
MyTable = "Table1"


'Erro handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:

'dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("H500").Value

dbPath = "H:\Annie\File.accdb"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
sql = "SELECT MAX([" & PrimaryField & "]) FROM [" & MyTable & "];"

'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
'Object Linking and Embedding, Database

'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-

'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options

rst.Open Source:="Table1", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

'rst.Open sql, cnn


GetLastPrimaryKey = rst.Fields(0).Value
MsgBox (GetLastPrimaryKey)
GetLastPrimaryKey = Arec1.Value
'you now have the recordset object
'alternative code
With rst
    .AddNew
    .Fields("ID").Value = Arec1
    .Fields("patient").Value = Arec2
    .Fields("test").Value = Arec3
    .Fields("CommentTxt").Value = Arec4
    .Update
End With


'clear the userform values
For x = 1 To 4
UserForm1.Controls("Arec" & x).Value = ""
Next
'add the next user ID
'Me.Arec1 = Sheet1.Range("J3").Value
' Close the connection
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
'commuinicate with the user
MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure cmdAdd"


End Sub
```

Comment: Forgive me, but why not do everything in MS Access? Why reinvent an entire user interface and query processor in Excel as Access does such operations natively.

Comment: The original report is dumped into Excel. Also, I work with people that refuse to use Access.  They are afraid of it. :)

Comment: Ah yes, Excel's popularity and ease of use are its own drawbacks as people will use it for everything under the sun! If you design a good UI in Access, users should not be afraid as they use command buttons, dropdowns, text boxes everyday on websites! Plus, Access forms are much more interactive than Excel UserForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider opening a new recordset. Of course, change the Excel userform textbox name (placeholder here):

```
Set maxIDrst = New ADODB.Recordset

sql = "SELECT MAX([" & PrimaryField & "]) + 1 as MaxIDPlusOne FROM [" & MyTable & "];"
maxIDrst.Open sql, conn

UserForm1.Controls("Arec5").Value = maxIDrst!MaxIDPlusOne
maxIDrst.Close
...
Set maxIDrst = nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.  I've added your code and now get "Error 3001 (Arguments are of wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another" error.  Could you please help resolve this error?

Comment: here is what I've changed:`code Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath Set maxIDrst = New ADODB.Recordset sql = "SELECT MAX([" & PrimaryField & "]) + 1 as MaxIDPlusOne FROM [" & MyTable & "];" maxIDrst.Open sql, conn UserForm1.Arec1.Value = maxIDrst!MaxIDPlusOne Set maxIDrst = Nothing Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset rst.Open Source:="Table1", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _ CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _ Options:=adCmdTable `

Comment: Did your change work? I believe the earlier error was due to the UserForm control reference. As I mentioned in my answer, you need to change it to fit your intended textbox. I added a 5th to Arec because I thought the other four were in use already (ID, patient, test, CommentTxt).

Comment: I've created two seperated routines: one to query MaxId and the second to send the data to Access and they work great! Thank you for your help.